# My CSS doesn't do anything to the HTML file

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to implement the CSS to the HTML file but it's just not working, it doesn't matter what I try. I'm 100% sure I'm missing something, could anyone tell me what is it please?

Thanks!!!

```css
  :root {
  --content-width: 80%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  :root {
    --content-width: 95%;
  }
  html,
  body {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  div#content {
    background-color: hsl(209, 100%, 90%);
    width: var(--content-width, 80%);
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0 20px 100px 20px;
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  #img-div {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: hsl(209, 100%, 90%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  figure {
    border: 2px solid hsl(212, 55%, 54%);
    border-radius: 2%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 640px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  }
  figure:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.01);
    transform: scale(1.01);
  }
  img#image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Queen</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Look here the first example https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Please indent your code and properly indent it using the helpful code tool

Answer (score 0):

By checking your CSS, I have found two minor issues.

1. In the first root selector, you have space in between : and root. I think the correct syntax is `:root`
2. You are missing a curly bracket `}`. You have to add it after the second time you selected the root, or at the end of all the CSS styles according to your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the missing the closing bracket `}` in your media query is the culprit.

Having said that, it should not affect the styles applied before it. If however, even that is not is not working, it may be because of wrong location of css file given to your html file in the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

The above line means that your `css` file is in the same directory as the `html` file. If it is not so, your css codes will not work.

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Happy to help :)